# android service that print text to android screen

Tags: android, android-layout

as in the title i want to make an android service that write text to screen while it running i use this in main activity and it work  :

1- `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

but it fails to work  in the service .

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not mentioned service in Manifest file.
Put your service in your manifest file.

```
    <service android:name=".Service"/>
```

**Your manifest file will look like**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".Service"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it'll print message in Screen. If you want to do more UI operation in you can create [Bounded Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#CreatingBoundService) or Use [LocalBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(ServiceClassName.this, "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Try to put service class name.this